# Property does not exist on type array of interface

Tags: angular6

I am trying to solve this error below. It is not a problem running the application but once I run 'npm start', I see failed to compile and because of the error below.

> Property 'matches' does not exist on type 'Match[]'

This is http.get function from external api

```
getdata(id: string): Observable<Match[]>
  {
    this.setURL(id);
    return this.http.get<Match[]>(this.apiurl, httpOptions).pipe(map((res) => res));
  }
```

This is a function fro receiving the response

```
  private history: Match[];
  getHistory(id: string): void {
    this.summonerHistoryService.getdata(id)
    .subscribe((his) => {
        //console.log(his);
        this.history = his.matches;
```

This is an interface called "Match"

```
export interface Match{
    lane: string;
    gameId: number;
    champion: number;
    platformId: string;
    timestamp: number;
    queue: number;
    role: string;
    season: number;
}
```

A format of the response from the get is

```
endIndex:5
matches:(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
startIndex:0
totalGames:144
```

So What I did is simply getting that "matches" from the response and save that into history. However, I kept getting the error.
not sure how to retrieve an array of something which is the part of the response.

Comment: Is the sample response to the get you should the actual result that you receive from that call?  It seems weird to me, in that it doesn't look like a JSON object, so I dom't know how you would get matches from it by just saying `his.matches` ...

Comment: The HTTP class return a `Response` object, not your object type. Try this `map((res) => res.json());`

Comment: @moilejter yes the format of the response above is the actual result that I should get. I assume that the response from the get is JSON because the external api I am using is supposed to return JSON object. I guess "matches" itself is not JSON but that whole "his" is JSON object.

Comment: @BráulioFigueiredo I will try that and I will get back to you if it doesn't work :)